# Determine if all letters in a string are in alphabetical order JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, oop, sorting

I'm attempting to write a JavaScript function to determine if all letters in a string are in alphabetical order. The following would keep returning "SyntaxError: Unexpected token default"

```
function orderedWords(str) {
    var s=str.toLowerCase().split("");
    for(var i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
        var default = s[i];
        if (s[i+1] >= default)
            default = s[i+1];
        else return false;
    }
    return true;
}

orderedWords("aaabcdefffz"); // true
orderedWords("abcdefzjjab"); // false
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

`default` is a keyword in JavaScript, and cannot be a variable name.

EDIT: Also, you have a logic issue: if you iterate up to `length`, in your last iteration you will check the last character against `undefined`; the test will fail, and you will `return false`. Rewrite into:

```
for(var i=0; i<s.length - 1; i++) {
```

EDIT2: I am not actually even sure why you're using that variable, since it has no bearing to the rest of your code. This should work as well (also, I moved the range from `[0..length-1)` to `[1..length)` for easier calculation):

```
function orderedWords(str) {
    var s=str.toLowerCase().split("");
    for(var i=1; i<s.length; i++) {
        if (s[i - 1] > s[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

EDIT3: Simpler, shorter:

```
function orderedWords(str) {
    return str == str.split('').sort().join('');
}
```

Comment: @Marc: Indeed. The first two edits I was mostly concerned with rewriting OP's code, and I missed the `split` thing.

Comment: Thanks so much for the thorough answer. In comparing for (var i=0; i<s.length; i++) and for (var i=1; i<s.length-1; i++), I am wondering what are the advantages of using one over the other? Or are they essentially identical?

Comment: In one of them you are subtracting `1` every iteration, in the other you aren't. Also, one of them has a couple of characters less.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking for more than a sort? With this function you can use any letter order defined in map, and also the function removes punctuation just in case you need to check messy strings.

```
var map = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

function orderedWords(str,map){
    str = str.replace(/(.)(?=.*\1)/g, "");
    str = str.replace(/\W/g, '');
    var test = ""
    for(var i in map){
        if(str.indexOf(map[i])>-1){
            test += map[i];
        }
    }
    if(test.toLowerCase() == str.toLowerCase()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(orderedWords("aaabcdefffz", map));
console.log(orderedWords("abcdefzjjab", map));
```