# Drag a button in jQueryUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Html code is here

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery UI: alphabetmatcher</title>

        <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="matchalphabate.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- jQuery UI CSS -->
        <link href="js/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Drag and arrange alphabet</h1>

            <div id="dragable">
                <h3>Alphabate Table</h3>

                <button class="b">I</button>
                <button class="b">U</button>
                <button class="b">I</button>
                <button class="b">U</button>
                <button class="b">I</button>
                <button class="b">U</button>
                <button class="b">I</button>
                <button class="b">U</button>
                <button class="b">I</button>
                <button class="b">U</button>
                <button class="b">I</button>
                <button class="b">U</button>
                <button class="b">I</button>
                <button class="b">U</button>
                <button class="b">I</button>
                <button class="b">U</button>
                <button class="b">I</button>
                <button class="b">I</button>
                <button class="b">U</button>
                <button class="b">I</button>
                <button class="b">U</button>
                <button class="b">I</button>
                <button class="b">U</button>
                <button class="b">I</button>
                <button class="b">U</button>
                <button class="b">I</button>
            </div>

            <h4>Arrange now</h4>

            <ul id="sortableToo">
                <li>Other Item A</li>
                <li>Other Item B</li>
                <li>Other Item C</li>
                <li>Other Item D</li>
                <li>Other Item E</li>
                <li>Other Item F</li>
                <li>Other Item A</li>
                <li>Other Item B</li>
                <li>Other Item C</li>
                <li>Other Item D</li>
                <li>Other Item E</li>
                <li>Other Item E</li>
                <li>Other Item F</li>
            </ul>

            <ul id="sortableToo">
                <li>Other Item F</li>
                <li>Other Item A</li>
                <li>Other Item B</li>
                <li>Other Item C</li>
                <li>Other Item D</li>
                <li>Other Item E</li>
                <li>Other Item F</li>
                <li>Other Item A</li>
                <li>Other Item B</li>
                <li>Other Item C</li>
                <li>Other Item D</li>
                <li>Other Item E</li>
                <li>Other Item F</li>
            </ul>
            <a href="" class="button">Submit</a>
            <a href="" class="button alt-button"> Reset</a>
        </div>
        <!-- .container -->

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script>
            window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"><\script>');
        </script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>    
        <script src="js/matchalphabate.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS code is here

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width:1000px;
    height: 1500px;
    margin: 40px auto;
    background:#234567;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 10px  10px 10px 10px #333;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    color:dimgrey;
    color: aliceblue;
    text-shadow: 2px -10px black;   
}

#dragable{        
    height: 400px;
    width: 900px;
    background:#7c345d;
    box-sizing:content-box;
    border: solid 1px #ddd;
    padding: 20px;
}

h3,h4{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: aqua;
    text-shadow: 2px -10px black;        
}


.alphabate{
    position: relative;        
    height:30px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 0 0 1px;
    margin: 0  1px;        
}

.b{
    position: relative;        
    height:30px;
    width:100px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin:  10PX auto;
}

ul {
    width: 48%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 1%;
    list-style: none;
}

ul li  {
    background: #eee;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 2px 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 340px;        
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
}

ul li:hover {
    background: #ddd;
    border-color: #aaa;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul li:active {
    transform: rotate(2deg);
    background: #ccc;
    border-color: #999;
    box-shadow: 0 10px -4px #111;
}

.placeholderBox {
    background: #fc3;
    height: 20px;
    border: dashed 2px #777;
}

.button{
    display: inline-block;
    background:#f99;
    background: linear-gradient(green,aqua);
    border: solid 1px #999;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 30px 20px;
    margin: 80px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow:0 1px 3px aqua;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left:200px;        
}
```

jQuery is here

```
$(function (){
    $(".b").draggable();
});
```

I want to pick an alphabet  using the drag or drop on the table **when the alphabet is fully arranged like A-Z  then show the message on click submit button or reset again arrange alphabet in previous position**

Now button is not dragging alphabet A-Z also tell me about the condition when I drag alphabet and drop the list and click the submit button a message show for successfully arranged.

Answer (score 0):

you can't drag the `button` but can be made for each `button` a `div` **draggable**

like it:

```js
$( function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
  } );
```

```css
.draggable { width:300px;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>

  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
  <div  class="draggable ui-widget-content">
   <button>notDraggable</button>
   <button>notDraggable</button>
   <button>notDraggable</button>
   but draggable div
  </div>
  <div  class="draggable ui-widget-content">
   <button>notDraggable</button>
   but draggable div
  </div>
  <div  class="draggable ui-widget-content">
   <button>notDraggable</button>
   but draggable div
  </div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, @Nourein any idea about how I check arranged alphabet when click on  the submit button they show message arranged or condition failed the show unarranged

Comment: I do not understand exactly what you want
But you may want to see this / 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28620703/determine-if-all-letters-in-a-string-are-in-alphabetical-order-javascript